# calling POST request through jBPM

Tags: jbpm

I am trying to call a POST service through jBPM and getting the following error

`Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Content type may not be null`

my POST request is

```
    public String changeOrderStatus(@RequestBody String order){
        System.out.println("Post");
        return "success";
    }
```

and my jBPM service task has these input/output
[image]

What is the reason for the error. When I omit the `@RequestBody`, the post works. but I need to send data. can someone explain.

Also I do not find any online content for different REST calls for jBPM. I am working on a new project and we are planning to use jBPM. Should I use it or try other BPM opensource engine?

Comment: what is the ContentType?

Comment: ContentType variable is the parameter which is added by default when u add REST service Task in jBPM

Comment: I mean what is it's value here?

Comment: application/json

Comment: you will have the same problem in any other BPM engine, the problem is in your code and in how you are calling your service, please provide more details of your code to solve it

Comment: You were right, there was a trailing SPACE in Variable name for ContentType.

Comment: great to hear that

Answer (score 0):

We can close this question as owner of this question @Afroz Shaikh answered his question inside comments:
"You were right, there was a trailing SPACE in Variable name for ContentType."